# Failed to add test package pub upgrade failed (1)

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to add test package but it fails

```
Because every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on test_api 0.2.4 and test >=1.6.4 depends on test_api 0.2.6, flutter_test from sdk is incompatible with test >=1.6.4.
So, because ride_app depends on both test 1.6.4 and flutter_test any from sdk, version solving failed.
```

Pubspec

```
dev_dependencies:
  test: 1.6.4
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Comment: What if you downgrade test or upgrade the rest of your packages?

Comment: I solved this problem by simply not specifying a version for the `test` package. That is, my line reads only `test:`. I'm not sure if this is the best solution, but it worked for me.